# Heteroskedasticity and Unbiased estimators

Tags: heteroscedasticity

I'm just new to regression. I would like to know if I'm having a linear model. Does unbiasedness breakdown if i fail to account for heteroskedasticity?

Comment: Please explain your problem some more. What does "I'm having a linear model" mean? Bias towards what? What is your use case etc.

Comment: I think you mean failure to have homoskedasticity?  It is heteroskedasticity that causes the difficulty.

Comment: Okay, I would like to know if unbiasedness breaks down if one fails to account for heteroskedasticity in a given model. like why

Comment: anything @MichaelChernick????

Comment: @Pai Neto Thank you I understand your question.  I will look into it to see if I can come up with a good answer.

Comment: The answer is simple: unbiasedness is inherently different from heteroscedasticity, and unbiasedness in the usual linear model does not in anyway depend on homoscedasticity. So no, unbiasedness does not breakdown it remains

Comment: Thanks a lot @Repmat, I think I relate to the answer. It was really of much help coz I was getting hard time finding the effects of unbiased estimators.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is yes. **If you apply ordinary least squares to obtain the parameter estimates of the regression coefficients in linear regression,  estimates will all still be unbiased** if all assumptions hold other than homoscedasticity.  **Heteroscedasticity causes model misspecification and can hurt predictions** if not accounted for. But in the face of heteroscedasticity the least squares estimates remain unbiased.  You can find this on wikipedia under the title of heteroscedasticity.  A search of this site should turn up information on this also. You should check for possible duplicates to your question.

Another point about OLS, **the Gauss-Markov theorem** states that the least squares estimates of the regression parameters are **the best linear unbiased estimates even when the error terms are correlated** but the model is still homoscedastic.